# How to create a string literal type for keys of an indexable type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, union, string-literals

I have an indexable type in TypeScript with keys that can either be strings or numbers, like so:

```
export type MyRecords = { [name: string]: string | number };

const myRecords: MyRecords = {
  foo: 'a',
  bar: 1,
};
```

I want to create a string literal type that includes only the string keys of this type, so that I can use it to ensure type safety in my code. For example:

```
type KeysOfMyRecords = /* ??? */;

const key: KeysOfMyRecords = 'foo'; // should be OK
const invalidKey: KeysOfMyRecords = 'invalid'; // should cause a  error
```

I have tried the following without success:

```
type KeysOfMyRecords = keyof typeof myRecords;
```

Would this be possible?

Comment: If you want to do that you can't declare `MyRecords` to be a record type (e.g. `Record<string, string | number>` or the way you wrote it). You would have to declare *specific* keys with *specific* types. You can have dynamism or you can have statically defined compile time keys, but you can't have both (at least not in the way you're doing it).

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought too, I thought perhaps there was a way out, but apparently not.

Comment: Note that TS is structurally typed, even if you don't annotate it `myRecords` [qualifies as that type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyiBKwDG0AmAznALxwDecA2gHYCGAtsAFxyExQCWNA5gLqt2XXnAA+cGgFcGAI2BQ4AXwDcAKFV4a7OAyy4CxMuVVw4AMwgRWAcjrWANCbgy6UVgEZHK9Zu0Wr6Hp4UESkOkEGqkA). You *could* leave it unannotated, then you could use a recursive conditional type to pull out the ones with string values.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WYeAgW) using the `satisfies` operator instead of an annotation meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer (although I think there are probably existing questions that this would duplicate); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Do we only want foo above and not bar @cyrus-d?

Comment: While the @TusharShahi answer does work, I think "satisfies" is more appropriate. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a generic to achieve this:

```
export type MyRecords<T extends string | number | symbol> = Record<T, string | number>

const myRecords : MyRecords<'foo' | 'bar'>= {
  foo: 'a',
  bar: 1,
};


type KeysOfMyRecords = keyof typeof myRecords;

const key: KeysOfMyRecords = 'foo'; // should be OK
const invalidKey: KeysOfMyRecords = 'invalid'; // should cause a  error
```

The downside as you saw above is that you will have to mention the keys while defining your object.

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyiBKwDG0AmAzgDwAqcoMwAdkXITFAJbUDmcAPnNQK4C2AI2BRO9RIIgAbAHxwAvHGx4o+MgBp6jFuy69Bw6QChDeagzh8suAoTgAudFeVFiAcgBmECK9GuBAQyhXaQUAb0M4OE8IB1d-VzUIuACoBwBGRIBfOH9bUwYAbmNDJBQ4AGlgREIAeXcMJRt5OABrKoh3BGRgDosnGyKTCDN4NsQHSuq6husVWwUPL1cCuAB6VfoACwgeSXxk1BryoZG4FgA3f0kmfEmJqtr6-rnm1wurm+W1jcJt3f2cP4eIRUP5IsIoNAgA)

The issue with your expectation is that we want `myRecords` to be of a certain type `MyRecords`. Now we have explicityle defined `MyRecords` type to be having string as key, and that means any string. We could also have used `const` assertion in your code directly but it would not guarantee type safety with `MyRecords` type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was hoping not to modify MyRecords, and it appears that the "satisfies" feature is the only way to accomplish this.