# Retrieve keys from defined object in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to retrieve the keys from a defined object in Typescript. You can find the [playground here](https://tsplay.dev/Wzk6Ew) with information on actual and expected output.

```js
// I want users to define a variable (or const) of type A
// and then extract the keys from A

type A = {
  [key: string]: 123,
}

const aTyped: A = {
  myKey: 123,
} as const;

type ExtractKeys<T> = keyof T;

type Keys = ExtractKeys<typeof aTyped>; // expected: Keys = 'myKey'
                                        // actual value: string | number :(
```

Comment: Object.keys(aTyped) should give you myKey

Comment: This looks the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76157070/2887218) so it's been linked. If you annotate as `A` then the game is over; instead you will need something like the `satisfies` operator, so you change it from `const aTyped: A = ⋯;` to `const aTyped = ⋯ satisfies A;`

Comment: @jcalz Thank you, this solved my problem. To be fair, I would be completely lost without your continuous support here on SO. ;)